# Help expressing a fraction as a finite series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For the life of me I can't figure out how to prove the following equality by direct calculation

> $$
> \frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(x+h)^jx^{n-j-1}
> $$

The working I've done thus far is as follows.
$$
\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}=\frac{1}{h}\left(\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}x^{n-i}h^i-x^n\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{h}\sum_{i=1}^n{n\choose i}x^{n-i}h^i
$$
introduce the substitution $j=i-1$, then our expression becomes
$$
=\frac{1}{h}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{n\choose j+1}x^{n-j-1}h^{j+1}
$$
$$
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{n\choose j+1}h^jx^{n-j-1}
$$
So, for me, it appears the problem comes down to whether I can write
$$
{n\choose j+1}h^j
$$
as just $(x+h)^j$. To introduce $x$, I thought it may be a good idea to start with $h^j=(h+x-x)^j$, but this approach hasn't gotten me anywhere thus far. Any help is appreciated (for anyone interested, this is a problem I encountered whilst self-studying real analysis, and is not related to a homework problem or anything similar).

Comment: One thing to point out: using $a^n-b^n = (a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right)$ gives the intended result almost immediately.

Comment: @KM101 Is this by any chance supposed to read $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$? Thanks for reminding me that this identity exists.

Comment: Yeah, I already corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}=\frac{x^n}{h}[ (1+h/n)^n-1]= \frac{x^n}{h} \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k}\left(\frac{h}{x}\right)^k=\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-k} h^{k-1}$$